# XCode doesn't honor the "iOS Distribution" Code Signing Entity setting

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, codesign

I want correctly understand the Code Signing Identity setting: I want to use the automatic setting in Xcode and not specify a specific identity. The automatic setting has 2 choices: iOS Developer and iOS Distribution. Based on which one you use, it's supposed to switch to choose a developer or a distribution signing identity from your keychain.

I have my build settings configured as follow, in order to use an "iOS Distribution" identity on build:

[image: Build Settings]

When I **Archive** my app (the Archive scheme is correctly set to use the **Release** build configuration), I see that Xcode is not using the correct code signing identity:

[image: Build log]

Anyone would know why this is the case? I'm looking for an explanation and not a workaround solution (I know I can work around the problem by directly setting the Code Signing Identity to my *iPhone Distribution: Company Name* identity from the keychain)

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try setting the provisioning profile just a little further downward?

Comment: According to "No Such Provisioning Profile Was Found" on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html, this is supposed to be set to None.

Comment: Did you set Provisioning Profile to Distribution too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So interestingly this doesn't actually matter in the latest Xcode as long as the profile you are eventually going to sign with is for the same bundle identifier as the one its signing with now...

As long as the team setting is set Xcode is capable of generating the profile you need automatically. Don't try to fight it.

Here is the Team setting from the Target's General settings screen:
[image: team setting]

Then when you archive Xcode puts the archive in the organiser. When you click distribute on the archive in the organiser window it prompts you to select a new signing identity and actually re-signs the app.

It actually works to sign apps with the team provisioning profiles generated by Xcode. You also don't need to make an ad-hoc specific provisioning profile as your testers can now install apps signed using the development provisioning profiles with no issues. The only time you will need to make your own provisioning profile is if you are using any of the concrete bundle id features like push notifications, game centre, data protection, iCloud, inter-app audio, passbook, keychain access groups or in-app purchase.

If you make your own provisioning profiles for specific bundle ids then Xcode will either automatically select, or have available for selection, the relevant provisioning profile at the point of choosing the identity in the organiser window.

[image: choosing a profile from the organiser window]

You can refresh Xcode's cache of provisioning profiles from the Accounts pane of Xcode's settings. Click on your team, Click "View Details" and then click the tiny refresh button in the bottom left corner

[image: account pane of Xcode prefs]

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense but do you know why then I'm getting the following error with TestFlight: "The keychain-access-group in the embedded.mobileprovision and your binary don't match." 

According to this I was thinking I had to sign using a distribution entity to make sure the prefix match (developer entity has a wildcard prefix which maybe doesn't match the prefix in the Adhoc profile)

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402843-mismatched-keychain-access-groups

Comment: This usually happens when the provisioning profile you select when you re-sign from the organiser window is actually in a different team to your Target's team setting.

Comment: I only have one team, I don't think this would be the case. I noticed that for my other apps, XCode created development provisioning profiles that exactly match the app ID while for this one it's using a provisioning profile with a wildcard.

Comment: Ha. I refreshed Xcode's cache and it seems to be creating on the provisioning portal a development provisioning profile exactly matching the App ID.

Comment: I'll put money on that fixing it.

Comment: Cool. Xcode does select the right identity and provisioning profile (iOS developer identity + team provisioining profile with right app ID).

TestFlight doesn't want to resign the profile with the Adhoc provisioning profile complaining that the app was build with a development provisioning profile. However, if I resign with the Xcode Organizer and then upload the build to TestFlight, it works fine. Any idea why TestFlight adds this limitation?